# KQL change order of columns in evaluate pivot

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

I have the following query:

```
let fooTable = datatable(TIMESTAMP: datetime, list_id: int, dim_count: int) [
    datetime("2022-01-17T08:00:00Z"), -1, 120,
    datetime("2022-01-17T08:00:00Z"), 1, 50,
    datetime("2022-01-17T08:00:00Z"), 2, 30,
    datetime("2022-01-17T08:00:00Z"), 8, 30,
    datetime("2022-01-17T08:00:00Z"), 2001, 30,
    datetime("2022-01-17T08:00:00Z"), 4, 30,
];
fooTable
| order by TIMESTAMP desc, dim_count desc 
| evaluate pivot(list_id, take_any(dim_count), TIMESTAMP)
```

This produces the following results:

```
TIMESTAMP                   1   -1  2   2001    4   8
2022-01-17T08:00:00Z        50  120 30  30     30   30
```

Which produce almost what I need - grouping the TIMESTAMP value and creating a column for each `list_id` value, to use the `dim_count` as value.

But I expected a different order of the columns (like in the input).

```
TIMESTAMP                   -1  1   2   8   2001    4
2022-01-17T08:00:00Z        120 50  30  30     30   30
```

How can I order the columns in such way? (the number and value of columns are dynamic).
Or, how can I control the order of the returned columns?

In reality I have more data (with more buckets of time), and I'd want to return the columns in the order of the largest sum of the column (`dim_count`).
So the order of the columns in the output would like:

```
fooTable
| summarize sum(dim_count) by list_id
| order  by  sum_dim_count desc 
| project list_id
```

Which produces

```
-1
1
2
8
2001
4
```

And this is how I'd like the order of the columns (like in my expected output).

Comment: Where is the order of the columns matter? The access to columns in KQL is always by name, so the order should not matter.

Comment: @Avnera Matters only on the consumer side. So I'd rather compute this in the ADX rather than in my program. the Order is `let theOrder = fooTable | summarize sum(dim_count) by  list_id | order  by  sum_dim_count desc | project list_id;`. Perhaps there's a way to `project-reorder` by this `theOrder` array variable?

Answer (score 3):

If the order is based on the [row_number](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/rownumberfunction), you can use it with the [project-reorder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/projectreorderoperator) operator, the client will need to parse the column names and remove the prefix, for example:

```
let fooTable = datatable(TIMESTAMP: datetime, list_id: int, dim_count: int) [
    datetime("2022-01-17T08:00:00Z"), -1, 120,
    datetime("2022-01-17T08:00:00Z"), 1, 50,
    datetime("2022-01-17T08:00:00Z"), 2, 30,
    datetime("2022-01-17T08:00:00Z"), 8, 30,
    datetime("2022-01-17T08:00:00Z"), 2001, 30,
    datetime("2022-01-17T08:00:00Z"), 4, 30,
];
fooTable
| serialize 
| extend list_id = strcat(row_number(), "_", list_id)
| order by TIMESTAMP desc, dim_count desc 
| evaluate pivot(list_id, take_any(dim_count), TIMESTAMP)
| project-reorder *
```

| TIMESTAMP | 1_-1 | 2_1 | 3_2 | 4_8 | 5_2001 | 6_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-17 08:00:00.0000000 | 120 | 50 | 30 | 30 | 30 | 30 |